# Why Am I not getting add a new key and value to an existence object?

Tags: javascript

I Have the follow object which iterating it I can add a new key and value, but when I have to make a database search and take each result and add as a new key + value does not work, the Eslint point a `Assignment to property of function parameter 'object'.eslintno-param-reassign`, bellow is the example without make a database search.

```js
const obj = {
  Cod: 43453,
  Informations: [
    {
      codPay: 802112,
      value: 80
    },
    {
      codPay: 802113,
      value: 80
    },
    {
      codPay: 802114,
      value: 80
    },
    {
      codPay: 802115,
      value: 80
    },
    {
      codPay: 802116,
      value: 80
    },
    {
      codPay: 802117,
      value: 80
    },
    {
      codPay: 802118,
      value: 80
    },
    {
      codPay: 802119,
      value: 80
    }
  ],
  status: 'OK'
}



obj["Informations"].forEach((f,index) => {
    f.more_info = index
})

console.log(obj)
```

By making database search:

```
obj["Informations"].forEach(asyn(f) => {
    const result = db.any("Select info From table where cod $1",f.codPay")
    f.more_info = result[0].info
})
```

by openning this `db.any`  the values is coming correct but I cannot add new key, where Am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The `no-param-reassign` rule is there to warn you that mutating the argument may cause undesirable effects elsewhere in the code. For example, there may be some other part of the code that relies on the assumption that each `Informations` sub-object contains only `codPay` and `value` properties, and nothing else (no `more_info` property). If such code existed, your addition of a `more_info` property could cause that code to stop working.

A good alternative is to use `.map`, to create *entirely new* objects instead of mutating the original ones. That will fix the linter warning.

Another issue is that it looks like `db.any` returns a Promise, in which case you should wait for it to resolve first. To do this in a loop, use `Promise.all` to wait for all Promises in an array to resolve.

```
const informationsWithMoreInfo = await Promise.all(
    obj.Informations.map(
        obj => db.any("Select info From table where cod $1", obj.codPay)
            .then(result => ({ ...obj, more_info: result[0].info }))
    )
);
// do stuff with informationsWithMoreInfo
```

For the `await` to work, make sure the containing function is `async` - either that, or call `.then` on the Promise.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the `cod`  is a param which is catch inside `obj.forEach(elem .. `  , the select must be called inside first loop

Comment: None of the `Informations` sub-objects have a `cod` property. Did you mean `.codPay`?